# Expect an array to contain a string using webdriver.io

Tags: javascript, testing, webdriver, webdriver-io, wdio

How can I write my test so that it expects my array to contain a specific string? I've tried what I have below and some other methods such as using `array.includes` but can't get it to work properly.

```
let value = "test4";
let dropdownValues = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];

expect(dropdownValues).toHaveTextContaining(value);
```

Comment: @Prophet Sorry not sure what you mean by that. What answers am I not accepting?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: @Prophet “ Accepting an answer is not mandatory; do not feel compelled to accept the first answer you receive.” In past posts I don’t think anyone has given me the best answer for me to accept. Not sure why you felt the need to waste time bringing that up instead of helping out with this question

Comment: Because upvoting and accepting answers are 1)Kind of saying thanks to person who tried to help you 2)Accepting answer indicates the question is resolved. Just try to understand that here you are getting for absolutely free highly qualified help normally your would pay for that a lot of money. So, just saying "Thanks" in this this case is something basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to go about this is to set a variable that checks if the array contains a certain string and use that variable in the expect statement:

```
let value = "test4";
let dropdownValues = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];
let valueExist = dropdownValues.includes(value);

expect(valueExist).toEqual(true);
```